# How to Change typeface in VideoView in android?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I have a `VideoView` in xml file. and I have MediaController on it, it shows current time and duration. I want to know how can I change Typeface of these times?

Comment: what does `VideoView` have to do with Typeface?

Comment: @pskink: I said in my question, font of times that are displayed like current time and duration of that video

Comment: you mean `android.widget.VideoView`? it just shows your video, not any "times"

Comment: yes your right I put media controler on it

Comment: but nobody knows what "media controller" you put on it

Comment: I changed my question, thanks